# Converting PDF to Site Pages in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, wiki-pages

We are trying to create a wiki. Currently we have PDF files which we planning to convert into site pages. The pdf file has lot of images. Can someone suggest what is best way to convert images PDF into a site page in SharePoint Online?
I would appreciate any help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Currently I dont't think we could converting PDF to site pages in SharePoint online.

And I couldn't find any third-party tools to meet your requirement.

From the standpoint of SharePoint，we could use Power Automate (Flow) to Convert SharePoint Online Wiki Pages to PDF:

https://kamdaryash.wordpress.com/2020/03/24/use-powerautomate-flow-to-convert-sharepoint-online-wiki-pages-to-pdf/